# php hacer INSERT INTO a partir de un OBJETO

Tags: php, poo

tengo mi siguiente funcion que debe **insertar un usuario** a partir de un objeto `Usuario.php` que se le pase por parametro. 
Aqui la funcion:

```
public function insertar($usuario){
         if (get_class($usuario) === "Usuario") {
            $this->conexion->conectar();
            if ($this->conexion != null) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais,fecha_registro) 
                    VALUES(
                    '".$usuario['nombre']."',
                    '".$usuario['apellidos']."',
                    '".$usuario['email']."',
                    '".$usuario['password']."',
                    '".$usuario['fecha_nacimiento']."',
                    '".$usuario['pais']."',
                    '".$usuario['fecha_registro']."'
                );";
                $result = $this->conexion->getConnection()->query($sql);

                var_dump($result);


            } else {

            }

         } else {
            return false;
         }
    }
```

Pero me da los siguientes **errores** :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Usuario as array in 

Error: Cannot use object of type Usuario as array in
```

Ambos **errores** me dan en la misma linea. La linea donde esta los `VALUES` del `INSERT INTO`

Comment: `$usuario` es un objeto y lo estas tratando como array

Comment: Cierto, es verdad. No me fije en eso. Muchas gracias

Comment: Aparte veo 2 posibles problemas adicionales. Compruebas que `$this->conexion != null` despues de hacer `$this->conexion->conectar();`, estte puede dar problemas. Ademas deberías usar sentencias preparadas para evitar inyección sql.

Answer (score 3):

En este caso debes utilizar $usuario como objeto, no como array. Puedes solucionarlo cambiando los `$usuario['propiedad']` por `$usuario->propiedad`

```
                    VALUES(
                    '".$usuario->nombre."',
                    '".$usuario->apellidos."',
                    '".$usuario->email."',
                    '".$usuario->password."',
                    '".$usuario->fecha_nacimiento."',
                    '".$usuario->pais."',
                    '".$usuario->fecha_registro."'
                );";
```

Esto SIEMPRE Y CUANDO tu objeto tenga publicas las propiedades indicadas. Si por el contrario tienes metodos get/set y las propiedades son privadas, entonces debes cambiarlo por algo tipo:

`$usuario->getNombre()`

`$usuario->get('nombre')`

O como tengas definida tu clase $usuario

Comment: Si, ya me percate, Muchas gracias